# Some icons/symbols in TeXstudio are missing

Tags: themes, gui, xfce

[image]

Just installed TeXstudio on Xubuntu 13.10 (the theme is Numix) and there are lots of icons/symbols missing. Is it rather related to TeXstudio or because of the the theme? If the latter, what do I have to do to  make it work? I'd rather stay with Numix.

Comment: When you say that _the theme is Numix,_ are you referring to an icon theme (in `/usr/share/icons`) or the gtk theme (in `/usr/share/themes`)? I'm asking because Xubuntu 13.10 has introduced a gtk theme called Numix while there also is a Numix icon theme and a Numix project ppa.

Comment: I'm referring to the built-in Numix theme, the one which was shipped with Xubuntu 13.10. However the problem above occurred after I switched to one Numix icon theme which I installed over their PPA and then back to the default theme... if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solution found via google on [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/831/):

```
 sudo apt-get install libqt4-svg
```

It actually was a re-installation but it worked anyway.

Comment: I had the same problem with Lubuntu 14.04 with the TeXstudio version available from the Ubuntu repository (2.6.6) and this solution (sudo apt-get install libqt4-svg) also worked for me. Thanks! :-)

Comment: same on Ubuntu 14.04: had to (force) reinstall libqt4-svg, then it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me as well, running standard Ubuntu 17.10 and GNOME.

Comment: @AdrianKeister So this is still relevant. Wow. :)