# Missing icons in fresh texstudio installation

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce, gui, text-editor

I just installed the texstudio version **xUbuntu 14.04 amd64 2.12.6 QT 4** from a .deb file downloaded from the [texstudio](http://www.texstudio.org/) website. This fresh installed version is missing a bunch of symbols as one can see from the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxUwf.png). When I run the program via line command the following messages are threw:

```
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
Cannot open file ':/images-ng/error.svgz', because: Unknown error
Cannot open file ':/images-ng/error.svgz', because: Unknown error
Cannot open file ':/images-ng/warning.svgz', because: Unknown error
Cannot open file ':/images-ng/warning.svgz', because: Unknown error
Cannot open file ':/images-ng/badbox.svg', because: Unknown error
Cannot open file ':/images-ng/badbox.svg', because: Unknown error
Unknown toolbar command main/latex/sectioning
Unknown toolbar command main/latex/references
Unknown toolbar command main/latex/fontsizes
Unknown toolbar command main/latex/fontstyles/textbf
Unknown toolbar command main/latex/fontstyles/textit
Unknown toolbar command main/latex/fontstyles/underline
Unknown toolbar command main/latex/environment/flushleft
Unknown toolbar command main/latex/environment/center
Unknown toolbar command main/latex/environment/flushright
Unknown toolbar command main/latex/spacing/newline
Unknown toolbar command main/math/mathmode
Unknown toolbar command main/math/subscript
Unknown toolbar command main/math/superscript
Unknown toolbar command main/math/frac
Unknown toolbar command main/math/dfrac
Unknown toolbar command main/math/sqrt
```

I found this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400975/some-icons-symbols-in-texstudio-are-missing) with the same issue, but the proposed solution did not work for me. Any tip on how could I solve this problem?

My Linux version is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

installed via a Xubuntu flavor, which has Xfce desktop envinroment.

Comment: Similar problem on 17.04

Comment: @adn, if you solve this issue, can you report the solution? Here, I still without sucess.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, I uninstalled Texstudio and installed the **QT5** version instead, even though it is stated explicitly "*For Ubuntu 14.04 use Qt4 Version.*"

This is not a fix but it is a workaround for being productive today.